# Installing openjdk-7-jre blocked when "setting up ca-certificates-java" on Debian

Tags: docker, debian, java

I'm trying to install jre in a docker-container, and use 
`RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre` to install jre in my container. When I started to build it, the process blocked at this command:
`Setting up ca-certificates-java (20140324)...`

Here is the screenshot:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pTmO.jpg)

My dockerfile is from *debian:jessie*:

```
COPY ./data /runtime/data
RUN chmod 777 -R /runtime/data  
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre && \
    apt-get install -y screen && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem:

```
[...]
Setting up openjdk-7-jre:amd64 (7u101-2.6.6-1~deb8u1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/policytool to provide /usr/bin/policytool (policytool) in auto mode
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20140324) ...
done.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18+deb8u4) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (215-17+deb8u4) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20141019+deb8u1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 174 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....
[...]
```

What is your Docker version ?

Comment: Docker Version:1.11.1,API version:1.23

Comment: Hi,

Same as mine but I have no problem building your image.

My image is the same as your without `COPY ./data /runtime/data` and `RUN chmod 777 -R /runtime/data`